# how the fwmark works together with mask in ip rule command

Tags: linux, ip

I try to understand how the `ip rule add fwmark` works together with `mask`,

for example:
`ip rule` command show the following rule:
100:    from all fwmark 0xd00/0xffffff00 lookup 6017

so if there a packet with mark "0xd70" arrives, it will try to match the mark in the ip rules, but how the "0xd70" is calucated with the fwmark and the mask "0xd00/0xffffff00"?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the answer? ip-rule's manpage stays silent on this, unfortunately. I have a guess but I would like to not rely on that guess. My guess is that an fwmark of `0xd70` would match `0xd00/0xffffff00` because the mask is first applied (bitwise and) to the incoming fwmark and then compared to the rule's fwmark. So, the mask is about controlling which bits are tested (1) and which bits are ignored (0).

Answer (score 2):

There is no too much info about `fwmask` from `iproute` or kernel's release note. Finally, I have to get the `fwmask`'s real meaning from kernel code as following,

```C
static int fib_rule_match(struct fib_rule *rule, struct fib_rules_ops *ops, struct flowi *fl, int flags, struct fib_lookup_arg *arg)
{
  int ret = 0;
  if (rule->iifindex && (rule->iifindex != fl->flowi_iif))
     goto out;
  if (rule->oifindex && (rule->oifindex != fl->flowi_oif))
     goto out;
  if ((rule->mark ^ fl->flowi_mark) & rule->mark_mask)  <<<<<<<<<<<
     goto out;
  if (rule->tun_id && (rule->tun_id != fl->flowi_tun_key.tun_id))
     goto out;
  if (rule->l3mdev && !l3mdev_fib_rule_match(rule->fr_net, fl, arg))
     goto out;
  if (uid_lt(fl->flowi_uid, rule->uid_range.start) || uid_gt(fl->flowi_uid, rule->uid_range.end))
     goto out;
    
  ret = ops->match(rule, fl, flags);

  out:
  return (rule->flags & FIB_RULE_INVERT) ? !ret : ret;
}
```

And specifically, the `fwmark`/`fwmask` `0xXYZ`/`0xFFFFFFFF` means only the mark itself can match the rule.

```C
int fib_nl_newrule(struct sk_buff *skb, struct nlmsghdr *nlh, struct netlink_ext_ack *extack)
{
  struct net *net = sock_net(skb->sk);
  struct fib_rule_hdr *frh = nlmsg_data(nlh);
  ...

  if (tb[FRA_FWMARK]) {
    rule->mark = nla_get_u32(tb[FRA_FWMARK]);
    if (rule->mark)
      /* compatibility: if the mark value is non-zero all bits
       * are compared unless a mask is explicitly specified.
       */
     rule->mark_mask = 0xFFFFFFFF; <<<<<<<<<<<
  }
```